# How to write "any span that is a child of label is extended by x, whether it has a class or not" using SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like that every `span` that is a child of a `label` receive an extension, and at the same time simplify the SASS and remove repetition.

e.g. I'd like to rewrite this:

```
label > span {
  extend @informational;
}

label > span.info {
  extend @informational;
  /* other info stuff */
}

label > span.error {
  extend @informational;
  /* other error stuff */
}
```

Into something resembling this:

```
label {
  span {
    extend @informational;
  }

  span.info {
    /* other info stuff */
    /* this also gets extended, but no explicit extension statement here */
  }
  span.error {
    /* other error stuff */
    /* this also gets extended, but no explicit extension statement here */
  }
}
```

because just extending the `span` does not also extend a `span.xxx` (though I'd expect it to).

Is there a way? All the combinations I've attempted (including the one above) have failed.

I've also tried this without using `@extend` but through repeating the CSS in `informational` within each relevant block, to the same effect. This makes it a CSS problem (afaics) but if it can be solved using SASS that's fine too.

Comment: In what way have other attempts failed? This looks to me like all child spans *should* get the information extension… Note that the second example drops the `>` requirement, but other than that looks just fine.

Comment: It fails in that it doesn't produce the same styling as the first, the span.info and span.error don't get the extension. I've got more classes than info and error so the repetition is really building up.

Comment: well you don't need to re-declare styling since @informational is applied to every <span>, I dont get your objective..

Comment: @Rito I've edited the question in an attempt to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have other style rules that are overriding whatever is in your `@informational` extension for your `span` elements with classes. That's as far as I can see as well...

If that is the case you'll have to keep your class selectors so they make up for the less specific `span` selector, but you can group them together like this so you don't have to repeat the `extend @informational;` statement (you'll also want to use `>` if you're specifically only looking for children, and not just descendants at any nesting level):

```
label {
  > span, > span.info, > span.error {
    extend @informational;
  }

  > span.info {
    /* other info stuff */
  }

  > span.error {
    /* other error stuff */
  }
}
```

If you're not interested in which specific classes your `span` elements have, as long as they either have or don't have a `class` attribute, you could use an attribute selector instead as a cheap hack:

```
label {
  > span, > span[class] {
    extend @informational;
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated. I also wonder if there are other rules overriding these, but that's partly the reason for trying to simplify and clean up the current stuff.